# how to split asynchronous methods into smaller parts and call them each after another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, asynchronous, puppeteer

I am playing with puppeteer to control browser and make some automated tests. my test scenario requires to perform a lot of async actions on 100 pages. I am able to open 100 pages and perform all actions in one time but it seems that it is too much to handle for my cpu. So i want to split it and put in queue, for eg 20 pages at a time.

about the code:
I have a module which contains an object that consists of key and array filled with calls to async methods. then i iterate over this object and create for each key a separate page in browser. I call async methods and wait to resolve.

```
export default {

  async checkAllKeys() {
    const requirementsMap = {
      key_1: [this.method1, this.method2, this.method3],
      key_2: [this.method1, this.method2, this.method3],
      ...
      key_100: [this.method1, this.method2, this.method3],
    };

    const result = {};
    const promises = [];

    Object.keys(requirementsMap).forEach(async (key) => {
      promises.push(new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        const newPage = await browser.newPage();

        await newPage.goto('http://www.example.com/');

        const requirements = requirementsMap[key];
        const promises1 = requirements.map(requirement => requirement.call(this, newPage).catch(() => 'error occurred'));

        result[key] = await Promise.all(promises1);
        await newPage.close();
        resolve();
      }));
    });

    await Promise.all(promises);
    return result;
  },

  async method1(newPage) {
    // do some async actions
  },
  async method2() {
    // and etc....
  },
};
```

How can i split this for smaller parts, and fire them each after another?

Comment: Avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern...

Comment: hey man, i want to help, but i don't read code with faulty indentation — cheers

Comment: @ChaseMoskal hi, edited code, could you take a look now? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by constructing batches of X number of requests, along the lines of:

```
const batchSize = 20;
const requirementKeysArr = Object.keys(requirementsMap);

while (requirementKeysArr.length > 0){
   //this line does the trick: extracts from the requirementKeysArr the first batchSize elements and puts them in the batch variable
   const batch = requirementKeysArr.splice(0, batchSize);
   await Promise.all(batch);
}
```

So, your code would look something like:

```
export default {

  async checkAllKeys() {
    const requirementsMap = {
      key_1: [this.method1, this.method2, this.method3],
      key_2: [this.method1, this.method2, this.method3],
      ...
      key_100: [this.method1, this.method2, this.method3],
    };

    const result = {};
    const promises = [];
    const batchSize = 20;
    const requirementKeysArr = Object.keys(requirementsMap);

    while (requirementKeysArr.length > 0){

       const batch = requirementKeysArr.splice(0, batchSize).map( async (key) => {
        const newPage = await browser.newPage();

        await newPage.goto('http://www.example.com/');

        const requirements = requirementsMap[key];
        const promises1 = requirements.map(requirement => requirement.call(this, newPage).catch(() => 'error occurred'));

        result[key] = await Promise.all(promises1);
        await newPage.close();
        return result[key];

});        

    await Promise.all(batch);
  } // end while
  return result;
  },

  async method1(newPage) {
    // do some async actions
  },
  async method2() {
    // and etc....
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should avoid explicitly creating promises wherever possible and fully embrace async logic. Something like this should work:

```
async function checkAllKeys() {
    const requirementsMap = {
      key_1: [method1, method2, method3],
      key_2: [method1, method2, method3],
      ... 
      key_100: [method1, method2, method3]
    };
    const resultsArray = await Promise.all(Object.entries(requirementsMap).map(async ([key, value]) => {
        const newPage = await browser.newPage();

        await newPage.goto('http://www.example.com/');

        const requirements = requirementsMap[key];
        const requirementsPromises = requirements.map(async (requirement) => {
            try {
                return requirement.call(this, newPage);
            } catch (e) {
                throw new Error('error occurred');
            }
        });

        const partialResult = await Promise.all(requirementsPromises);
        await newPage.close();
        return [key, partialResult];
    }));

    const results = resultsArray.reduce((obj, [key, partialResult]) => {
        obj[key] = partialResult;
    }, {});

    return results;
}
```

A few things to notice and be careful of:

1. Every time there is a promise that you want to pause execution until it is resolved, always use `await`.
2. If you want the promise to resolve asynchronously, *do not* use `await`. Only `await` when you want execution to stop.
3. Be careful of your use of `this`. I would avoid using it if possible since `this` always depends on how a function is called. instead, use explicit objects. There is almost never a time outside of a `class` when you want to use `this`. The only time this should happen is if you are using a legacy library which requires it for some reason.
4. When you run this in production, you will want to use a giant try-catch block around this and clearly log all errors.